# Exclude root node from xml using xmlserializer

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have a nested class which i use xmlserializer to convert it to xml.

```
public class RequestModel{

        [XmlElement("message", Namespace = "http://www.origostandards.com/schema/mtg/v2")]
        public Message message { get; set; }

        public RequestModel()
        {
            this.message = new Message();
        }
        public class Message
        {
           //other constructor here etc
        }
}
```

When it serializes it all compiles without issue however the output is as follows:

```
<RequestModel>
   <mtg:message>
   ...
   </mtg:message>
</RequestModel>
```

Is there a way to exclude the class name from serializing so that message would become the top node and the output would look like:

```
<mtg:message>
  ...
</mtg:message>
```

I have tried adding a Boolean for visibility of the node as well as things as XmlIgnore and XmlRoot but these attributes don't really fit with my solution.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Change the type in the serializer from RequestModel to Message.

Comment: I know that would work, however i have another class ResponseModel which follows the same structure and i need a way to distinguish between the two. If i were to change it then they would both be called Message?

Comment: Would both have the same root tag <mtg:message>?  What do you want the two root tags to look like?  If the two objects are in different c# namespaces then you can use the same name.  The c# namespece does get put into the xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try different c# namespaces :

```
namespace RequestA
{
    public class RequestModel
    {

        [XmlElement("message", Namespace = "http://www.origostandards.com/schema/mtg/v2")]
        public Message.Message message { get; set; }

        public RequestModel()
        {
            this.message = new Message.Message();
        }
     }
}
namespace RequestB
{

    public class RequestModel
    {
        [XmlElement("message", Namespace = "http://www.origostandards.com/schema/mtg/v2")]
        public Message.Message message { get; set; }

        public RequestModel()
        {
            this.message = new Message.Message();
        }
    }
}
namespace Message
{
        public class Message
        {
            //other constructor here etc
        }

}
```