# Exclude root node when do Xml serialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have similar problem to the one, which is discussed in the thread below:
[Exclude root node from xml using xmlserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440400/exclude-root-node-from-xml-using-xmlserializer/53231378#53231378)

I need to do the same thing as Smithy asked for in that thread. But if I change the type in the Serializer as jdweng suggested, say to Message as in the original example and than pass the instance of the RequestModel to serializer, than I have InvalidCastException which is saying to me that "Unable to cast object of type RequestModel to type Message. Implementation of the cast operators in RequestModel to cast from RequestModel to Message does not help. Smithy, how did it work in your case? 
Thanks.
Alex.

Comment: If you're using WCF you may want to consider using a [MessageContract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-message-contracts#defining-message-contracts). Otherwise, I guess you're better off serializing the Message object instead?

Comment: MessagContract seems to me is a good idea. Can I generate from the code Soap message from the class with MessageContract attribute?

Comment: Yes, if you generate code from an existing WSDL, the MessageContracts are generated for you with tools like svcutil.exe. Otherwise, if you are the one creating the service, simply return an object that is a MessageContract and the WCF framework will generate the SOAP message for you. Read the entire page in the link in my previous comment if you want to learn more about MessageContracts. If you're using SOAP and C#, use WCF.

Comment: My answer is not to the original question.  It was to the Ops response : I know that would work, however i have another class ResponseModel which follows the same structure and i need a way to distinguish between the two. If i were to change it then they would both be called Message?

Comment: The instance of the class you are serializing and the TYPE in the Serialize object must be the same.  So if you have RequestModel requestModel;  Then if you are serializing message you would serialize the instance : requestModel.message